# Is it possible to run Docker command from inside an Azure Pipelines container job?

Tags: docker, azure-pipelines

Azure Pipelines support [containerized jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

I tried to run a Docker command inside a container job:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'

container: ubuntu:16.04

steps:
- script: docker ps
```

And I got an error saying `command not found: docker`, which makes sense, as running Docker from inside a Docker container is not a standard use case.

However, I need to run a job inside a container to use a specific build tool, and I also need to publish Docker images from inside that container.

Is it possible to achieve it Azure Pipelines?

Comment: Just build your own image and use that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically, what you need to do is something like this:

1. create a dockerfile for your build agent
2. use that as a [build agent container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) or host it somewhere as a real build agent. in the latter case you'd need to map host docker to the container:

```
  volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /docker-volume
    name: docker-in-docker
  - mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
    name: docker-volume
volumes:
- name: docker-in-docker
  hostPath:
    path: /agent
- name: docker-volume
  hostPath:
    path: /var/run/docker.sock
```

you need both the socket and the hostpath, because if you want to map directories to the container, they have to be present on the host, docker builds are fine without folder sharing